# Chrome extension license validation always returns NO LICENSE

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension with free trial option. I followed the following url and am able to get a response from the license api.
  https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#update-manifest
  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity

However i am always getting the below response. License information is missing.

```
{"kind":"chromewebstore#userLicense","itemId":"my-app-id","result":false,"maxAgeSecs":"2"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was testing it with the developer google account instead of tester account. Now im getting proper response as below.

```
{"kind":"chromewebstore#userLicense","itemId":"my-app-id","createdTime":"1425237580974","result":true,"accessLevel":"FREE_TRIAL","maxAgeSecs":"2"}"
```

Comment: Hi some of my customers are still getting no license, do you have any idea?